# Doubt Regarding Noether's theorem for time-dependent systems

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

I'm having problems showing Noether's theorem when the lagrangian is time dependent. I'm trying to do it not using infinitesimal transformations from the beginning, but continuous transformations of a parameter and then deriving under the integral sign. When checking the result against books there seems to be a conflict, what books call $\psi$ in the infinitesimal transformations $q(t) + \lambda \psi(q(t))$ to me should be the partial derivative with respect to $\lambda$ of the transformation acting on the functions, but in my result is appearing as the total derivative with respect to the parameter, which, since time is also being transformed means that it depends jointly on the transformation being applied to time. The details of the attempted proof is below

A Lagrangian $L(\vec{x},\vec{y},z)$, a movement function $\vec{q}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and the action $S_I[\vec{q}] = \int_I L(\vec{q}(t),\dot{\vec{q}}(t),t) dt$. My understanding is that the parametrized transformations $G_{\lambda}[\vec{q}] = \vec{q}_{\lambda}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $h_{\lambda}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ;$ \ \ G_{0}[\vec{q}] = \vec{q}; \ \ h_{0}(t) = t$, are symmetries of the action if:

$$ S_I[\vec{q}] = S_{h_{\lambda}(I)}[G_{\lambda}[\vec{q}]]      $$

for every $q$ (no more arrows on top of vectors because it's tiresome). Which implies:

$$ \frac{dS_{h_{\lambda}(I)}[G_{\lambda}[q]]}{d\lambda}\bigg|_{\lambda=0} = 0$$

$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{h_{\lambda}(I)} L( \ G_{\lambda}[q(\xi)],  \ \ G_{\lambda}[q(\xi)]', \ \xi) \ d\xi \bigg|_{\lambda=0} =  $$

Changing variables to integrate over the original domain

$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{(I)} L\left( \ G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))],  \ \ G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]'\frac{1}{h'_{\lambda}(t)}, \ h_{\lambda}(t)\right) \ h'_{\lambda}(t)dt \bigg|_{\lambda=0} $$

And now applying the chain rule, $\frac{L}{\partial x}|_{\phi}$ is the gradient vector with respect to the position variables (same for $y$), since $G_{\lambda}[q]\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there is a ridden dot product there which is not explicit, apologies, but there is already to much notation.

$$  \int_I \frac{L}{\partial x}|_{\phi}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left\{ G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))] \right\} + \frac{L}{\partial y}|_{\phi}\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left\{G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]'\frac{1}{h'_{\lambda}(t)}\right\} - \frac{\partial L}{dz}|_{\phi}\frac{dh_{\lambda}(t)}{d\lambda}       + L\frac{d^2h_{\lambda}(t)}{d\lambda dt} \bigg|_{\lambda=0} dt$$

where $\phi(t) = (q(t),\dot{q}(t),t) $. Now, the derivative in the second term is:

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left\{G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]'\frac{1}{h'_{\lambda}(t)}\right\}|_{\lambda=0} = \frac{d^2}{d\lambda dt}G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]|_{\lambda=0}\frac{1}{h'_{\lambda=0}(t)} - G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]|_{\lambda=0} \dot{q}(t) \frac{dh'_{\lambda}(t)}{d\lambda}|_{\lambda=0}\frac{1}{h'_{\lambda=0}(t)^2} $$

commuting the derivatives of $\lambda$ and $t$, and evaluating things at $\lambda=0$ we have:

$$= \frac{d}{dt}\left\{ \frac{d}{d\lambda} G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]\right\}|_{\lambda=0}  - \dot{q}(t)\frac{dh'_{\lambda}(t)}{d\lambda}|_{\lambda=0}     $$

If we suppose that $q(t)$ is a minimum of the action, apply the Euler Lagrange equations and group things together nicely we arrive at

$$ \frac{\partial L}{dy}|_{\phi} \frac{d}{d\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))] |_{\lambda=0} - H|_{\phi} \frac{d}{d\lambda}h_{\lambda}(t)|_{\lambda=0} = constant               $$

Which is very similar to equation (2.168) of Nivaldo A. Lemos's - Analytical Mechanic (2018), if $\psi = \frac{d}{d\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]$, but to me it would only makes sense if it were $\psi = \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(h_{\lambda}(t))]|_{\lambda=0} = \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(t)]|_{\lambda=0}  $. The difference is that $G$ is really a function of two variables, one of which takes values in the space of movement functions and the other in the reals, $G[q,\lambda]$. The infinitesimal generator of $G_\lambda$ should be the partial derivative of $G$ with respect to the second entry, the entry of the parameter, tell us only how the second entry of $G$ effects the transformation, otherwise the infinitesimal generator of $G$ depends on $h_{\lambda}$. The total derivative of $\lambda$ is what appears in the equation, this involves the partial derivative of $G$ with respect to the parameter plus the derivative of $G$ with respect to the function $q$ (which is not a problem because evaluated at zero is simply the identity) times $\dot{q}(t) \frac{d}{d\lambda}h_{\lambda}|_{\lambda=0}$. Expanding this derivative we should have

$$ \frac{\partial L}{dy}|_{\phi} \left(\dot{q}(t)\frac{d}{d\lambda}h_{\lambda}|_{\lambda=0} + \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(t)]|_{\lambda=0}\right) -  H|_{\phi} \frac{d}{d\lambda}h_{\lambda}(t) = cta    $$

Getting rid of the hamiltonian this would be:

$$  L \frac{d}{d\lambda}h_\lambda(t)|_{\lambda=0} + \frac{\partial L}{dy}|_{\phi}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}G_{\lambda}[q(t)]|_{\lambda=0} = cta          $$

Which is not in any book as "Noether's Theorem" so must be wrong. Is the problem somewhere in the calculations or I'm just not getting the result?

Comment: This is definitely way overkill for the result we want to obtain. And in your so fully-fleshed-out scheme, there is no real need to restrict yourself to $\lambda=0$. It is too complicated to immediately see if everything is correct, but at least the logical flow seems ok. The complication in your result also prevents it from being presented in textbooks; just because it has not appeared in books is not a reliable indicator that it is wrong for this case.